# GUI for playlist / equivalent to WPF ListView in Java?

Tags: java, wpf, swing, listview, playlist

Using Swing I need to create a GUI showing a playlist. The playlist should look like in the image below: A title (like Song xyz) and an image for it (e.g. representing the file type like MP3, OGG...). In WPF I would use a ListView for that, but in that case I need to use Java and Swing - what's the best way to do something like that in Java/Swing? It would also be nice if drag & drop (rearranging items, e.g. drag title 3 before titel 1) is possible. Thanks for any hint!

[image]

Hint: Of course this is just a sketch and title and image should be vertically centered in the rows ;-)

Comment: See also [*How to Use Lists*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

Comment: This might be helpful: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/features/components.html

Comment: @trashgod  Fulfilling the OPs entire spec., `JList` should be entered as an answer (IMO).

Comment: Sorry, out of time. I like the link cited by @home.